# How I can fix that the bot spams the message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to code a bot event that sends a message to a certain channel whenever a certain person comes online. But when the event is triggered the bot spams the message. how can i fix it?

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(after.status) == "online" and after.id == MyID:
        channel = bot.get_channel (941209391917568000) 
        await channel.send("idk")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to ensure the string value of after and before are not the same.

E.g. change

```
if str(after.status) == "online" and after.id == MyID:
```

to

```
if str(after.status) == "online" and after.id == MyID and str(after.status) !== str(before.status)
```